# Project/Gradle files broken after upgrading to Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

I recently updated Android Studio from version 2.1 to 2.2 and my previously working project has major build errors, centering around a "gradle failed to sync" message I got when opening the project for the first time in version 2.2

It seems that some update occurred to gradle when I did the Studio upgrade to version 2.2, and this update has broken my old project's references (I think). All editing/debugging/simulation features aren't usable within Android Studio when I open this project. What did I do wrong when upgrading, and more importantly how can I fix my broken project and restore full Android Studio functionality while editing this project like I had when running version 2.1.

In the image below you will notice i'm getting a message about a VCS root misconfiguration and all of my toolbar buttons (run, debug, etc) are grayed out. [image: Studio has severely limited functionality after upgrade]

What can I do to fix this?

I've included my build.gradle file below

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: First try updating to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Same configuration should work.
click on configure VCS(the popup in right side).And to enable Run, Debug etc options, select module(android app module)to run from dropdown option(in left of run option).
For Instant Run to work , update Gradle to 2.2.0-beta3 or higher.